# How to create a layout which will take 4/5 to screen width android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm implementing a horizontal recycler view which Trending category cardviews are something like this image [image]

but I achieved this by fixing the width. for small screen cardview covers whole width which I don't want my code is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="1dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/trendimage"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/trendtitle"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="Zakir Khan's Event"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:background="#88000000"
            android:textColor="@color/icons" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/place_white_24dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe the `values`  `values-w320dp` would help ;)

Comment: you need to calculate  height and width dramatically according parentage.

Comment: @Chetan  no any xml way to do that?

Comment: Then you should use weights or new constraintView .

Comment: can you please provide code for that.. constraint layout is new I tried that by could not able to achive that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can need to calculate the width of the screen and take 4/5 of that to set into you onBindViewHolder call of Adapter. You can set the layout param(width) of item view there.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html).

*Step 1:*
Add the percent support library into your module gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.0'
```

*Step 2:*
Add percentage width into your layouts:

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:layout_widthPercent="80%"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="1dp">

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/trendimage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/test"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trendtitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="#88000000"
                android:hint="Test Event"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

            <ImageView
                app:layout_widthPercent="10%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/test"/>

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

The results that i am getting: 
[image]

I hope this helps

Comment: top layout is match_parent it will create extra gap??

Comment: the "match_parent" property in the parent LinearLayout will allocate the whole length of the view to the LinearLayout. With the provided weightSum property inside the parent layout, it specifies that the children views can be distributed according to the weightSum provided inside the parent LinearLayout and when we specify layout_weight property to 4, then it allocates the exact width asper your requirements that is '4/5'

Comment: see the above image ... and its recycler view cards so if I define match_parent width.. then second cards will be placed after some space ..

Comment: You are talking about the recyclerView with 'trending' heading and Arijit Singh's picture , right ?

Comment: Ok, so you want the views to be attached without any additional white spaces ?

Comment: not working layout_width is required ... match_parent or wrap_content whatever i am setting it take up full screen

Comment: Resolved it and tested the code with an EditText in my Android Studio. Please check the updated answer, thanks.

Comment: now blank is showing ... no cardview is showing right now

Comment: Its showing at design time but after loading data its gone

Comment: normally its working perfect but inside recycler view its hiding its content... anyway I achived this other way.. thanks for you help

Comment: Ok, no problem :)